# Bonita BPM returns 0.00 in several columns

Tags: bonita

I created 3 variables which i used to do calculations

i called one (First Variable) `numberOfNights = Name , Value = numberOfNights type = String`, `the second one (Second Variable) perdiem = Name , Value = perdiem type = String` and the last one 
 is a javascript expression i used for some calculations

Now i used some Javascript function like this :

```
var CalculateAmount = Number($data.perdiem) * Number($data.numberOfNights);
return CalculateAmount
```

when i created another variable of Type Javascript Expression with name PerdiemCalculateDays , now i save. Which i then bound to the input widget totalAmount

Now i have this as my FormInput which is suppose to hold the Data

```
{
  "travelRequestInput" : {
    "departureDate" : null,
     "numberOfNights":0,
    "fullname" : "",
    "hotelNeeded" : false,
    "origin" : "",
    "destination" : "",
    "reason" : "",
    "supervisorName" : "",
    "supervisorEmail" : "",
    "perdiem":0,
    "totalAmount":0
  }
}
```

And formOutput which is supposed to save the Data inside the Database looks like this :

```
return {
    'travelRequestInput': $data.formInput.travelRequestInput,
    'numberOfNights': $data.numberOfNights,
    'perdiem': $data.perdiem,
    'totalAmount': $data.PerdiemCalculateDays.value
};
```

but instead i get empty columns inside the Database with 0.00 every whre like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg6nm.png)

Asides that other things seem to work pretty good , the connectors and workflows are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that the structure of the contract you define to start a process instance does not match the JSON structure you are sending.

This mismatch come from the way you are building the JavaScript object reference by the formOutput variable.

You should review the definition of formOutput value and bind your form widgets directly to the formInput attributes (formOutput will reuse information stored in formInput).

If you need more details about form variables, submit button and contract you can read an [answer](https://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/using-javascript-expression-and-saving-database) I provide on Bonitasoft community forum.